# Dlookup with multiple criteria return the same result

Tags: ms-access

When I run the following query,

**Dlookup("[Service Description]","[Roster_QC]","[ID]=" & [ID]-1 AND "'[Person]= '" & [Person]&"'")**

It showed the same result every time.
What I try to achieve is to let the Dlookup return for the previous service description when the person is the same.

Appreciate your insights or solution to this. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have an extraneous apostrophe and incorrect concatenation.

```
Dlookup("[Service Description]", "[Roster_QC]", "[ID]=" & [ID]-1 & " AND [Person]= '" & [Person] & "'")
```

That approach assumes there are no gaps in ID sequence. If there are gaps, expect incorrect results. Alternative query where gaps are irrelevant:

```
SELECT Roster_QC.*, (SELECT TOP 1 Dupe.[Service Description] FROM Roster_QC AS Dupe
    WHERE Dupe.Person = Roster_QC.Person AND Dupe.ID<Roster_QC.ID
    ORDER BY Dupe.ID DESC) AS Prev
FROM Roster_QC;
```

Comment: You are LEGEND!!